# Determine the range of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Tags: analysis, functions, trigonometry

I am having trouble understanding the solution to this question.

''Determine the range of the following function:

$f(x)$ = $(1$  $if$  $x=0)$ or (${\sin x\over x}$ if $x$$\neq$$0$)
where the domain is the set $E$=($-\infty$,0)$\cup$(0,$\infty$).

Answer:
The answer for the range is $R=(c,1]$ where $c=-\cos x_0$, such that $x_0$ is the smallest positive solution of $x=\tan x$. ''

Could someone please explain how we get this range?

Thanks

Comment: find the critical numbers of $f$. global maximum is $1$ sat $x = 0$. to find the global minimum you need the critical numbers given by $\tan x = x$

Comment: We want to see how far the range extends into the negative. The negative value with largest absolute value occurs in two places, symmetric about the origin. The positive place for the minimum is in the third quadrant, where the derivative is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

note that $f(0) = 1$ and $f$ is even. so we only need to worry about the global minimum on $0 \le x < \infty$

the critical numbers of $f$ defined by $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ are given by 
$ f^\prime(x)= \dfrac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x^2} = 0$ the positive critical numbers are the positive solutions $x \cos x - \sin x = 0$ which is equivalent to $\tan x = x$ this has a solution in $(\pi, 3/2 \pi) + k\pi$ where $k$ is nonnegative integer. the critical numbers corresponding to the even values of $k$ gives local min and odd values of $k$ give local max. the first local min is also the global min. let us call that $x_0$ which satisfies $\cos x_0 = \dfrac{\sin x_0}{x_0}$ and $\pi < x_0 < 3\pi/2.$  the range of $f$ is $[\cos x_0, 1]$

Comment: Thank you for the post. I agree with most of your answer, however, the supposed answer states that the range is from (-$\cos x_0$ , 1] whereas you have put down the positive value.

Comment: @rexregum, if $x_0$ is in the second quadrant. $\cos x_0$ is negative. now you can see that the range is in fact contains zero and includes negative values.

Answer (score 0):

The function $ sinc (x)= \dfrac{\sin x }{x}$ has maximum value 1 and minimum that can be found by Chain Rule when we have

$$\frac{\sin x }{x}=\frac{\cos x }{1}$$

or $$ \tan x = x $$

whose solution $x_{min}$ has to be  found graphically or numerically by iteration. Its corresponding $y_{min}$ negative value is evaluated. Then,

the range is $ 1>y> y_{min},$

because the graph shows the functon clinging to intermediate values of $y$.